# How faster the way using code VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

1. Using a VBA code to getting data from a column, then writing the data in to the next rigth of that column.
2. Using a VBA code to creating the function which is use to geting data from a cell, then writing the data to the next right of that cell. Using that function in the another cells.

NOTE: the data which is getting is the internet link of an image; the data which is writing is the image from that link.

Which is faster, 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code:

```
Sub TheFirstWay()
    Dim A As Range, B As Range
    Set A = Range("A1:A100")
    Set B = Range("B1:B100")
    B.Value = A.Value
End Sub
```

might be slightly faster than this code:

```
Sub TheSecondWay()
    Dim A As Range, B As Range
    Set A = Range("A1:A100")
    Set B = Range("B1:B100")
    B.Formula = "=A1"
End Sub
```

But if you keep changing the data in column **A**, you will have to keep re-running `TheFirstWay` macro.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: But, another problem here, i used the second method! Whenever i open the file, it update the data automaticly again XD! curiosity, both of 2 files which having the same size (MB) :C

Comment: **YES!** You see the difference between the two ways.  In the second way, the copy is dynamic..........if you change values in column **A**, the values in column **B** will also update.

Comment: That problem make me to thinking about what the excell doing with its data and formula extacly! May the excell re-run the formula again whenever we open the file?

Comment: WOW, thanks for the last answer! I had never think of what the excell doing with its data and formula extacly! now, i just get the valuable knowlegd ! Thanks so much